# Importing Jar from Gitlab package registry

Tags: scala, gitlab, sbt

I have a scala project and I want to import a dependency from another private repo (GitLab package registry) using SBT not using MAVEN or Gradle .. a bit lost and don't know where to start.

I already researched about it and don't know where to start.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Resolvers.html#URL

Answer (score 0):

That should be supported now with [GitLab 16.0](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#download-packages-from-the-maven-registry-with-scala) (May 2023):

> ### Download packages from the Maven Registry with Scala
>
> The GitLab Package Registry now supports downloading Maven packages using the Scala build tool (`sbt`).
>
> Previously, Scala users had no way to download Maven packages from the registry because basic authentication was not supported. As a result, Scala users were either blocked from using the registry or had to use Maven (`mvn`) or Gradle as an alternative.
>
> By adding support for Scala, we hope to help you use the Package Registry with your more data intensive projects.
>
> Please note that publishing artifacts using `sbt` is not yet supported, but you can follow [issue 408479](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/408479) if you are interested in adding support for publishing.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#install-a-package) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/212854).

```scala
// build.sbt
libraryDependencies += "com.mycompany.mydepartment" % "my-project" % "8.4"
// then run
sbt update
```

---

GitLab 16.8 (Jan. 2024) will support [uploading artifacts using SBT](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/408479#note_1716226257).

Answer (score 0):

Add to your project/plugins.sbt file this plugin:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.gilcloud"     % "sbt-gitlab"          % "0.0.6")
```

Then you must be sure your additional gitlab private project is publised in the section Build/artifacts (this should be using 'sbt publish' or 'sbt your-module / publish'). Once you are sure your jar is in gitlab you can add your dependency in your project as VonC mentioned.